# Using Select with ruby sockets what is a good way to ignore a given socket if a certain condition is met?

Tags: ruby, select, sockets

A little background:

I've written a script that will act as a receiver for incoming Syslog/Email/Snmp(v1) traps.  It receives the data and stores it as a custom defined object.  My "messageSocket" is a means to control the behavior from a script outside of this general listener.  I want to send messages to this to either start/stop on command.  The start / stop essentially just change the state of the @running variable.

All of this works fine, except when I stop - if I trigger an event that creates an e-mail/trap etc it won't be registered while @running = false.  However, as soon as I set @running = true it will still see this socket data and analyze it.

I tried removing the given socket from my @descriptors array, I tried closing sockets, I tried setting res to different values.  I'm guessing I'm just missing something at this point, any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
def run()  
   while 1 == 1

     res = select(@descriptors, nil, nil, nil)

     if res != nil then

        for sock in res[0]
          if sock == @mailSocket && @running == true then
            accept_new_connection
          elsif sock == @sysSocket && @running == true then
            get_syslog_message
          elsif sock == @snmpSocket && @running == true then
            get_snmp_message
          elsif sock == @mailSocket && @running == false then
            reject_mail
          elsif sock == @messageSocket then
            get_message()
          elsif sock == @snmpSocket && @running == false then
            #do something
          elsif sock == @sysSocket && @running == false then
            #do something
          end
        end   
      end
    end
 end
   #run end 
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall, `select` is (sort of) level driven, not edge driven.  In other words, if `select` returns descriptors and you do nothing with those descriptors, the next time you call `select` it will tell you again.

So, if you are not running, you still have to read the data (or whatever else is appropriate for the event), or `select` will just tell you again later.

To confirm my hypothesis, print "foo" right after the call to `select`, make `@running` be `false` and then try to establish a connection.  If you see "foo" scolling by over and over, showing that select is not blocking, then I'm right.  If you don't, I'll eat my words/delete my answer.

As an aside, you can (and should) simply say `@running` instead of `@running == true`, and `!@running` instead of `@running == false`

Comment: I can tell you that you are right because that is similar to something I had done before.  I also just verified it, select doesn't remove anything from @descriptors.  So I guess the real question is with a UDP socket how do I get rid of that data?  For e-mail I just spit back the expected Failure response.  When I tried to just receive all the data for syslog/snmp and not do anything it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer.  Thanks for making me revisit something I swear I had done :P  One of those days where I want to cry because its solved but also cry because I swear I tried it ;)

I created a reject_sys() method that just reads from the port and does nothing with the data.  Thanks!